# Error while trying to define input_size in the first layer of an 1D CNN

Tags: python, input, keras, conv-neural-network

I am trying to train an 1D CNN to recognise bearing faults using the data from the WCRU. I am having difficulties while defining the `input_shape` an the first layer of my model. My 'train_X' is a vector with dimensions (60800,1). This is the code I use:

```
X_train = numpy.loadtxt('training_dataX.txt',dtype=float)    
Y_train = numpy.loadtxt('training_dataY.txt',dtype=int)
X_test = numpy.loadtxt('testing_dataX.txt',dtype=float)
Y_test = numpy.loadtxt('testing_dataY.txt',dtype=int)

Y_train = np_utils.to_categorical(Y_train)                                     #one hot encode outputs
Y_test = np_utils.to_categorical(Y_test)
num_classes = Y_test.shape[1]

e=0.01                                                                         #create a callback to monitor the error to avoid overfitting
class myCallback(keras.callbacks.Callback):                                            
  def on_epoch_end(self, epoch, logs={}): 
      if(logs.get('val_loss') > e):   
          print("\nReached %2.2f%% error, so stopping training!!" %(e*100))   
          self.model.stop_training = True

def baseline_model():                                                          #building our sequential model
  model = Sequential()
  model.add(Conv1D(60,9,activation='tanh',padding='same',input_shape=(1,1)))
  model.add(MaxPooling1D(4))
  model.add(Conv1D(40,9,activation='tanh',padding='same'))
  model.add(MaxPooling1D(4))
  model.add(Conv1D(40,9,activation='tanh',padding='same'))
  model.add(Flatten())
  model.add(Dense(20,activation='tanh'))
  model.add(Dense(num_classes,activation='tanh'))
  model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',optimizer='adam',metrics=['accuracy'])
  return model

model = baseline_model()                                                       #initialize fitting process
model.fit(X_train, Y_train, validation_data=(X_test,Y_test),epochs=100,batch_size=10,callbacks=['callbacks'])

scores = model.evaluate(X_test,Y_test,verbose=0)                               #final model evaluation
print('CNN Error: %.2f%%' % (100-scores[1]*100))
```

Ufortunately I am getting this error message i cant figure out the reason:

```
ValueError: The shape of the input to "Flatten" is not fully defined (got (0, 40)). 
Make sure to pass a complete "input_shape" or "batch_input_shape" argument to the first layer in your model.
```

I 've tryied changing the `input_shape` to (1,) but the I get this error:

```
 ValueError: Input 0 is incompatible with layer conv1d_24: expected ndim=3, found ndim=2
```

Any suggestions would be appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, since you are doing classification, the final activation function should be `softmax` and not `tanh`. Second of all, if each example is a vector of dimension `(60800, 1)`, passing that as the input shape is necessary. Check code below:

```
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Input, Convolution1D, MaxPooling1D, GlobalAveragePooling1D, UpSampling1D, Conv1D, Flatten, Dense
input_shape = (60800, 1)
num_classes = 10
model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv1D(60,9,activation='tanh',padding='same',input_shape=input_shape))
model.add(MaxPooling1D(4))
model.add(Conv1D(40,9,activation='tanh',padding='same'))
model.add(MaxPooling1D(4))
model.add(Conv1D(40,9,activation='tanh',padding='same'))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(20,activation='tanh'))
model.add(Dense(num_classes,activation='softmax'))
model.summary()
```

**EDITS**

I used `num_classes` to be `10` because I do not know the number of classes, but you can change it accordingly.

Comment: Thak you for your respone. I did change my last activation to softmax after your suggestion thank for that i wasnt aware. 

second, I hod alreaydy tried to have the input_shape =(60800,1) but the error I got was that : 

ValueError: Error when checking input: expected conv1d_1_input to have 3 dimensions, but got array with shape (60800, 1)

Comment: That means there is a problem with your training set. Your `trainX` should have a shape of `(number_of_examples, 60800, 1)` so that during training, it could take batches of shape `(10, 60800, 1)`. Can you print the shape of your `trainX` and confirm?

Comment: you are right at that, in what excactly are you refering to when you are saying "number of exmaples" ?

Comment: number of examples means, how many training examples there are in your data. So when you load data to `X_train`, and do `print(X_train.shape)`, the first number printed should be the number of examples.